# SELECT * FROM "название стола в переменной"

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите плз реализацию правильного написания вот этого куска, чтобы название стола бралось из переменной с помощью метода Post

```
function show(){
global $connect;
$table_name = $_POST["имена"];
$connect->set_charset('utf8');
$query = "SELECT * FROM ('$table_name');"; \\ не рабочая строка
$result=mysqli_query($connect,$query);
$number_of_rows=mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: Можете добавить текст ошибки?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM ('$table_name');`  
Вы уверены в корректности самого запроса?  
`SELECT * FROM $table_name;`  
тоже не сработает?

Comment: А зачем скобки после `FROM`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table_name"; //php прекрасно понимает содержимое текстовых переменных, вы с кавычками и скобками преусердствовали.
```

Comment: Спасибо, заморочился0